# How Update item on the second page in WebForm wizard

Tags: 8, webforms

I am starting to work with webform in drupal 8 and I need to show values on the second page of the webform wizard, I have reviewed several solutions but I cannot do it. I tried using $ form_state-> setValue

```
function webform_certificadoemail_webform_element_alter(array &$element, FormStateInterface $form_state, array $context) {

  if ($form_state->get('current_page') == 'preview') {

    $value_entered = $form_state->getValue('nombre');
    drupal_set_message('Valor del nombre en el preview =:'.$value_entered); 

     $form_state->setValue('valor','This value is .......'); // This not work 
  }
}
```

Comment: Does your message show up? If not, you should use `if ($form['progress']['#current_page'] == 'preview') {`

Comment: Thanks for replying, the message in drupal_set_message if it appears, but  I can't update is the value field using the $ form_state-> setValue method ('value', 'This value is .......');

Comment: Are you trying to set a default value? Does the valor field appear in the preview step?

Comment: I explain my problem better, on the first page of the assistant I enter name, identity, etc. on the second page the data stored in postgresql should appear, I was reviewing examples and they use the method $ form_state-> setValue, where the name of the variable and the value in database are established. But when I go to the second page, those results are not displayed. Test with text field and compose token to display the result

Comment: So the value of "valor" is entered via textfield in step 1?

Comment: Yes, "valor" is text field

Answer (score 1):

When you are in the preview page, you're too late then.

You need to set this in your previous step in a validate function

```
function webform_certificadoemail_webform_element_alter(array &$element, FormStateInterface $form_state, array $context) {

   if ($form_state->get('current_page') == 'step_1') { // or whatever you called the first page
     $element['#element_validate'][] = 'webform_certificadoemail_set_valor';
  }

}

function webform_certificadoemail_set_valor($element, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
   $form_state->setValue('valor','This value is .......');
}
```

Comment: I was checking your code but it didn't work out, I don't know what I'm doing wrong. webform_certificadoemail_webform_element_alter(array &$element, FormStateInterface $form_state, array $context) {
   if ($form_state->get('current_page') == 'datos_de_solicitud') { // First page name
     $element['#element_validate'][] = 'webform_certificadoemail_set_valor';
  }
}

function webform_certificadoemail_set_valor($element, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
   $form_state->setValue('texto','This value is .......'); // "texto", text field key, "This value is ......." ,content of the field
}

Comment: Thank you very much, No Sssweat, check now again your code and now update the value, now what I have to do is place the code in another hook, because what I had is when an element of the webform was altered